# Multidimensional array fill

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, flood-fill

I'm trying to fill an area in a multidimensional array and not sure on the approach.

For example I have the following array:

```
var map = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

And then I am trying to get the number from X and Y position and fill all those numbers (which is 0) with a number given such as 1, which will result in the following array:

```
var map = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];
```

Basically just replacing all numbers next to each other (0) with (1) within that area.

What is the correct way to do this with JavaScript?

Comment: It is not clear top me what exactly you're trying to do.  How do you decide which `0` values should get changed to something else?

Comment: Looks a bit like a "fill" algorithm for a paint program:  the 2's form an enclosed "shape", and you want to fill the enclosed area with the number 1. (Just an observation.)

Comment: Yeah as BrettFromLA said I wish to fill the enclosed area with the number 1, though it can be any number - whichever is passed to the function etc

Comment: [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're given a starting position and you want to then fill all neighboring values up/down, left/right that contain the same value, you can do something like this:

```
var map = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

function fill(data, x, y, newValue) {
    // get target value
    var target = data[x][y];

    function flow(x,y) {
        // bounds check what we were passed
        if (x >= 0 && x < data.length && y >= 0 && y < data[x].length) {
            if (data[x][y] === target) {
                data[x][y] = newValue;
                flow(x-1, y);    // check up
                flow(x+1, y);    // check down
                flow(x, y-1);    // check left
                flow(x, y+1);    // check right
            }
        }
    }

    flow(x,y);
}

fill(map, 2, 2, 1);
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/C83AT/

---

Here's a version that doesn't use recursion and appears to work with large data sets.  Your large test data set wasn't a very interesting test pattern so I wouldn't say this is tested conclusively, but it seems to work on both the small and large data set:

Large data example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/8mrhN/

Small data example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/BFTub/ (easier to see the result)

```
function fill(data, x, y, newValue) {
    // get target value
    var target = data[x][y];
    // maintain list of cells to process
    // put the starting cell in the queue
    var queue = [{x:x, y:y}], item;

    while (queue.length) {
        item = queue.shift();
        x = item.x;
        y = item.y;
        if (data[x][y] === target) {
            data[x][y] = newValue;
            // up
            if (x > 0) {
                queue.push({x:x-1, y:y})
            }
            // down
            if (x + 1 < data.length) {
                queue.push({x:x+1, y:y})
            }
            // left
            if (y > 0) {
                queue.push({x:x, y:y-1});
            }
            // right
            if (y + 1 < data[x].length) {
                queue.push({x:x, y:y+1});
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This could be optimized further for performance by testing the value before putting it in the queue and by following a given direction until you find a non-matching value, if required.

Comment: Hi, thanks for posting, this works with small arrays but what about large arrays? it will get the "maximum call stack size exceeded" error. Lets say the width is 200 and height 200.

Comment: @user2909323 - post an array that you have that issue with and I'll look into it.

Comment: This looks like the [Stack-based recursive implementation (Four-way)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Stack-based_recursive_implementation_.28Four-way.29). Check out [Alternative implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations)

Comment: @Xotic750 - I'm aware that there are non-recursive implementations.  I've asked the OP to post a large sample data.  I tend to look for the simplest solution that solves the problem at hand and this met the OP's initial requirements so I went with the simple implementation.

Comment: I agree. I was really pointing the OP at the pseudo-code rather than you. :)

Comment: @user2909323 - I added a queue-based algorithm that does not use recursion and works on the large data set.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [alternative implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill#Alternative_implementations) (queue-based) roughly translated, no optimisations performed. There are also others.

Javascript

```
var map = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
];

/*
 1. Set Q to the empty queue.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Add node to Q.
 4. For each element N of Q:
 5.     If the color of N is equal to target-color:
 6.         Set w and e equal to N.
 7.         Move w to the west until the color of the node to the west of w no longer matches target-color.
 8.         Move e to the east until the color of the node to the east of e no longer matches target-color.
 9.         For each node n between w and e:
10.             Set the color of n to replacement-color.
11.             If the color of the node to the north of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
12.             If the color of the node to the south of n is target-color, add that node to Q.
13. Continue looping until Q is exhausted.
14. Return.
*/
function floodFill(data, node, targetValue, replacementValue) {
    var Q;

    if (data[node[0]][node[1]] === targetValue) {
        Q = [node];
        while (Q.length) {
            var N = Q.shift(),
                value,
                index,
                n,
                e,
                s,
                w;

            if (data.hasOwnProperty([N[0]]) && data[N[0]][N[1]] === targetValue) {
                w = e = N[0];
                do {
                    w -= 1;
                } while (data.hasOwnProperty(w) && data[w][N[1]] === targetValue);

                do {
                    e += 1;
                } while (data.hasOwnProperty(e) && data[e][N[1]] === targetValue);

                n = N[1] - 1;
                s = N[1] + 1;
                for (index = w + 1; index < e; index += 1) {
                    data[index][N[1]] = replacementValue;
                    if (data[index].hasOwnProperty(n) && data[index][n] === targetValue) {
                        Q.push([index, n]);
                    }

                    if (data[index].hasOwnProperty(s) && data[index][s] === targetValue) {
                        Q.push([index, s]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

floodFill(map, [2, 2], 0, 1);
map.forEach(function (m) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
});
```

Output

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0] 
[0,2,1,1,1,1,2,0,0]
[0,2,1,2,1,1,2,0,0] 
[0,2,1,1,2,1,2,0,0] 
[0,0,2,1,1,1,2,0,0] 
[0,0,0,2,2,2,2,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u72MC/)